# Laravel 4: Migration - Schema::table - Text column automatically creates primary unique index

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, phpmyadmin

I am creating a migration in Laravel with the following function:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('translate_item', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('lesson_id');
        $table->text('lang_1');
        $table->text('lang_2');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

The above creates the text fields as primary unique index as shown below:
[image]

Can anyone tell why this is happenning and how to create text fields without making it primary index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact they aren't created as primary key nor with unique index.

It maybe **look like** it. The fields are greyed out, because that's how phpMyAdmin displays columns you can't make primary key or unique.

No need to worry. `text()` does nothing you wouldn't expect.